# R: preventing par() from opening a new window when querying for grahical parameters

Tags: r, graphics, plot

The question says it all.
Sometimes you need to make preliminary calculations to format your plot and you don't want a window to show and most of all *stealing the focus*.

For example, say that you want to know the height of the lines used as margins, you might want to use:

```
par("mai")/par("mar")
```

I use to query often the graphical parameters to define what will be the figure output and find the popping window distracting and time consuming.

One possibility is to send everything to a bogus device with a custom quiet `par()`:

```
qpar=function(...){
    pdf()
    ret=par(...)
    dev.off()
    unlink('Rplots.pdf')
    ret
}
```

and so
without any noise:

```
par("mai")/qpar("mar") 
# [1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

It seems  a bit overkill and does not work for the `X11` device (or `windows()`).

Also `pdf.options()`,  `windows.options()` etc. are limited to a few device specific parameters.

Comment: the question doesnt make sense. par doesn't open a new window.. give more details, what do you need to calculate, what plotting functions are you using, does panel.first not meet your needs, an example of before and after when you have the calculations vs when you dont.. something..

Comment: @rawr: Well, maybe it doesn't, but on my system (Win7) every `par` query, say `par('fin')`, opens a new window stealing the focus.

Comment: If there is no graphical device
(this can be checked with `dev.list()`), 
`par()` creates one -- 
otherwise, there is nothing relevant to return.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd: I understand your point, but can we get the default values for a certain type of device before/without opening it?