# "Empty" graphics device to avoid opening new window with par

Tags: r, graphics

Consider the following:

```
dev.off()
dev.cur()  # null device
par("las") # opens a new device
dev.cur()  # default device
```

My problem is identical to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850788/r-preventing-par-from-opening-a-new-window-when-querying-for-grahical-paramet), I do not want to open a new device but the library I'm calling has unavoidable calls to `par()`. Also, I'd prefer a better solution than the hack described there.

My idea for solving it was the following:

change `options("device")` via

```
options(device = function(){}) # WARNING CHRASHES R WHEN CALLING PAR()
```

so that no new device get's opened. However as the comment indicates, this chrashes R. My question is, what should I change `options("device")` to such that no new device get's opened, but also R doesn't chrash when calling `par`.

Comment: What about `pdf(NULL)`?

Comment: Complain nicely to the package author to change the behaviour?

Comment: @Spacedman Complaining to the author would work, but I'm looking for a general solution. But it wouldn't prevent this error from occuring again with a new package.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin that is the solution in the linked post, which is more a hack imo.

Comment: Well, I believe it is best of what we have after `R_GD_nullDevice` got removed.

Comment: Coincidentally (maybe) my three-year old bug report of this crash behaviour got picked up by MM today: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15883 and there will be a fix in R-devel and 3.4.1-patched